# How do I make reference in order of appearance (not using Bibtex)?

Tags: bibliographies

I cited items using \cite{xxx} and started the reference section (not using Bibtex) with

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{xxx}
 ...
\end{thebibliography}
```

During the writing I type the reference not in order of appearance. 
How do I make the reference in the order of appearance automatically? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this. Reordering the references like this is actually a pretty complex task, and you really need the power of bibtex (or biblatex) to do this for you.

Comment: You have to order the `\bibitem` entries by hand if you do not use software to re-order them.

Comment: @ DavidCarlisle, how should I use a software, or do you have a certain method to recommend? Thanks!

Comment: @jsxs - If you create the contents of the `bibliography` environment by hand, *you* are in charge of everything, including the sort order. By construction, neither LaTeX nor BibTeX have a role in the process.

Comment: @ Mico, yes I know I have made a big trouble by typing the entries by myself. What should I do if I want to make life easier next time? Thanks!

Comment: @jsxs - It may not be too late to teach yourself the basics of setting up a `.bib` file and the various option for bibliographic entries -- `@article`, `@book`, etc -- and the fields (`author`, `title`, `year`, etc) recognized by each entry type. Then, choose a suitable bibliography style -- `unsrt` and `unsrtnat` come to mind... -- and rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to make the software create the bibliography for you.

Comment: @ Mico, I just managed to use Bibtex to do it. Thanks!

Comment: I meant bibtex (or biber) which are designed purely to sort bibliographies, but your question has "not using bibtex" in the title..)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the op managed to use BiBTeX to do the job. (That conflicts with the title not to use BibTeX ...)